# Accessing all (historical) events in Axon

Tags: time-series, axon

I am trying to build a service using Axon Framewok that would generate time series data that would be triggered by domain events, however, it would need access to the historic domain events to re-build the complete picture.

Possible domain events could be e.g. `CreateTimeseries`, `ModifyTimeseries`, and `EndTimeseries` events that would provide all the inputs needed to generate the final time series.

An example model with data might look something like this

```
CreateTimeseries { 
   min:0
   max: 0
   from: 2020-01-01
}
  
UpdateTimeseries {
    from: 2020-01-03
    to: 2020-01-05
    value: 20
}

UpdateTimeseries {
    from: 2020-01-22
    to: 2020-01-24
    value: 11
}
```

In this scenario, I have one `CreateTimeseries` event and several `ModifyTimeseries` events, which apply the changes that would need to be applied to the time series model, in a order (based on some event creation timestamp).

To implement this in through Axon Framework, would the "best practice" approach be to implement all this generation logic inside an Aggregate, as the aggregate would have access to all the previous domain events?

As an alternative to the Aggregate, is there a way that I can have a service with an Event Handler that reacts to the new events e.g. a new `TimeseriesUpdatedEvent`, but then somehow can access all the previous events that would be needed to generate the timeseries?

Comment: Would you be able to share a bit about the domain you are working in? So, what is in your mind going to publish those events? Is there a form of validation prior to publishing those events?

Answer (score 0):

Let me be upfront @vcetinick: I don't think this would belong in a form of Aggregate / Command Model right away.
My reasoning for this is based on thinking where a `TimeSeriesCreated`/`TimeSeriesUpdated` event would originate from. Which object/model would be in charge of deciding whether that has happened? Uncertain, given your current domain description, what that would be or what kind of business validation such an Aggregate would do at all.

Added, I'd like to warn you to move to a event form which resembles basic CRUD operation. A created event is something you would likely see in all scenarios, granted, albeit changed to register-, build-, construct-, etc. Update events however suggest a very generic change has occurred with your model, which could mean anything. You would loose the power that the event can describe *exactly* what has occurred. So, if at all possible inside your domain/application, I would recommend to publish more specific events, so that your event handlers are able to react more specifically.

Having said all that, when it comes to reacting to such events to build a "time series" model, I would drop this into a dedicated component with `@EventHandler` annotated methods in it, to update said model. Now, apparently there is a need to retroactively process events when a specific type of event is being handled.

This would be best placed in a regular Event Handling Component (so a class with `@EventHandler` annotated functions in it). How you draft up this time series model, can in my mind be resolved in two directions:

1. Use a time series database for this model, as then it is supported out of the box.
2. Do ad-hoc event store queries to retrieve additional events when handling a specific event.

Option one really comes down to selecting the time-series database you desire of course. And, drafting up the actual query model out there.

Option two comes down to using some additional Axon Framework components in your application. If you want to read events manually, you can simply wire the `EventStore` in the Event Handling Component, so that you can retrieve events either based on a given `aggregateIdentifier` or based on a given timestamp on the entire `EventStore` (defined in Axon as a `TrackingToken`).

You could take this a step further, by wrapping the time-series model (the exact class) in a `SimpleEventHandlerInvoker`. It is this last component which allows you to invoke the `handle(EventMessage)` method, so that you can stream over the retrieved set of events from the `EventStore`.

Hope this helps you further @vcetinick!